# Java Generics Interface casting

Tags: java, generics, interface, casting

I stumbled across a Java casting situation involving Generics and Interfaces that I do not understand.

Please consider the following code where I create a `List<Interface1>`. And then `get()` an element and cast it to `Interface2` without compiler error although these two interfaces are completely unrelated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String ... args) {
    List<Interface1> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Interface1() {});

    Interface1 ok = list.get(0);
    Interface2 why = (Interface2)list.get(0);
  }
}

interface Interface1 {
}

interface Interface2 {
}
```

Can anyone explain why there is not compiler error for the cast at the second `get(0)`?

Two side notes: Executing the class throws a `ClassCastException` (as expected). And using two classes instead of interfaces does actually generate compile errors.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This behaviour is unrelated to generics: you can cast any interface to any other without compile errors.

You cannot do this with classes because Java can check at compile time whether one class can be casted to another.

With interfaces however the cast might succeed or fail, depending on the class that is actually implementing the interface. This can be discovered only at runtime though.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a type which implements `Interface1` it may as well implement `Interface2`. Hence the compiler will not blame you, because at runtime the cast may succeed.

Answer (score 4):

There is possibility, that sub class of `Interface1` can be a sub class of `Interface2` also. So, it doesn't give the compilation error.

Answer (score 4):

This is because JAVA supports multiple interface implementations. As we can have any number of classes of any types(any parent class) that can implement an interface, JVM design is such that untill runtime one cannot identify which type is being passed in place that interface.So there can be any interface placed in the ArryList

Answer (score 4):

The compiler does not know that this won't work: You could have a instance of type **Interface2** that is also of type **Interface1** (for ex: class ImplementingClass implements Interface1,Interface2). Then the cast would be fine.

"using two classes instead of interfaces does actually generate compile errors."

In this situations compiler knows that it won't work, and due to this you are getting compilation error in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It not generic problem. JVM nothing "known" about compatibilities between `Interface1` and `Interface2`. So you get `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Incorrect, if an object implements both interfaces.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Here `Interface1` and `Interface2` two different interfaces.

Comment: Silviu's point is that the fact that Interface1 and Interface2 are different interfaces does not automatically imply that an instantiating object doesn't implement both.  Since the compiler can't know this it will allow the cast.  The ClassCastException occurs becausse the anonymous class does not implement Interface2.